# Django postgres constraint EXCLUDE WITH GIST

Tags: django, postgresql

I created a time field as follows:

```
start_date = models.DateField()
end_date = models.DateField()
```

When trying to create a constraint on the table with

```
 ALTER TABLE analytics
    EXCLUDE USING gist (campaign WITH =, tstzrange(start_date, end_date) WITH &&)
```

I get an error

```
ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting `date` to `timestamp with timezone` and that function is not immutable, but rather stable. It is like that because it will not always give the same result for the same argument passed.

I see 2 options here:

1) Change constraint to use daterange (or timestamp without timezone):

```
EXCLUDE USING gist (campaign WITH =, daterange(start_date, end_date) WITH &&)
```

2) Change type of those fields in table to timestamptz